# Spring Boot REST Mutltilingual

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there anyway to handle multi-lingual messages in Spring Boot - REST Services. I want to pass application messages (like Error, @valid messages) to front end application. Any reference would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot is built upon Spring Framework which in itself has excellent support for i18n, e.g. [this](http://www.journaldev.com/2610/spring-mvc-internationalization-i18n-and-localization-l10n-example) and [this](http://www.ekiras.com/2016/01/springboot-internalization-and-i18n.html)

Comment: good answer, perhaps you could quote relevant parts of the links you provided ?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer:  "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."